# Collecting all the tests implemented in pytest along with markers

Tags: python, pytest, test-plan, conftest

I am looking forward to list all the (pytest) test cases in the form of CSV.

Use case scenario:
We already have test cases defined for multiple platforms and databases. These test cases are organized/grouped based on different markers (Ex : platform_linux, platform_centos, db_maria, db_mongo, db_redis etc).

I want to create a CSV file, that contains all the markers and test cases that belong the marker.

Sample of CSV file:

```
> Marker, Test Cases
> platform_linux, [test_linux1, test_linux2...]
> db_mariadb, [test_mariadb1, test_mariadb2...]
```

Goal here is to process the CSV file and derive all the tests running on Linux platform with mariadb.

I did get get some answers on collecting test cases (--collect-only) can it be used to create desired CSV?, Do we have existing plugins to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a suitable plugin (though there are hundreds of them, so it may still exist), but you can implement this yourself by implementing [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems). You get there in the collection phase after all items are collected. The collected test items are passed there as a list, which you may use to write out the csv.

You would probably make this dependent on some option with the file name as value. Here is an example:

*top-level conftest.py*

```py
import csv

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--output-tests-csv", action="store", default=None)

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    csv_out = config.getoption("--output-tests-csv")
    if csv_out:
        tests = {}
        # collect all tests with matching markers
        for item in items:
            for mark in item.iter_markers():
                if mark.name.startswith(("platform_", "db_")):
                    tests.setdefault(mark.name, []).append(item.name)
        # write tests in csv (one line per marker)
        with open(csv_out, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for marker, tests in tests.items():
                writer.writerow([marker, tests])
```

This assumes that the markers to consider start with `platform_` or `db_`, you may have to adapt this, also the wanted csv format, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks Bremen, when does pytest_collection_modifyitems gets executed ? before the test run or after the test run ?, What is order of execution w.r.t pytest_itemcollected, pytest_collect_file

Comment: It is called after all tests are collected (clarified in the answer). `pytest_itemcollected` is called after each single test collected, so before that one.

Answer (score 0):

There is pytest-csv plugin that provides option to generate required CSV with markers, markers_as_parameters etc.

https://github.com/nicoulaj/pytest-csv

Sample usage (customizing the columns in the CSV):

```
py.test --csv tests.csv --csv-columns host,function,status,duration,parameters_as_columns
```

Note: requirement pytest >= 6.0